# Bootstrap 3: how to calculate gutter width for different container width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-layout, gutter

I changed the container width of bootstrap to 981px based on a design that was provided to me.

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container{
        max-width: 981px;
    }
}
```

I noticed that the gutter width is set to 30px, but how do I determine what is a good width when the container width is different?

I have want to keep the container max-width at 981px simply because of that's how the designer implemented the layout in Photoshop.

For example, there is an image that is 981px wide, which spans the entire width of the container.

Answer (score 0):

You can best achieve this by editing the less files themselves, rather than the compiled css.

If everything is nested properly, then all that's required is to override some variables (you can redefine variables, the last instance will rule, so just add these after importing the bootstrap styles):

less:

```
@import "../bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less";

// impractically large breakpoint for simplicity 
// now you've only got three breakpoints to play with :/
@screen-lg: 12000px;

@my-target-width: 981px;
@container-desktop: ((@my-target-width + @grid-gutter-width));
```

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-g-1200-500-2.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would say it'd be pretty impractical to override the required styles in css alone (if you're not using less or sass in the first place, you'd certainly miss some of the overrides you'd need to make in the compiled css).

I'd definitely recommend embracing the learning curve and using bootstrap with less or sass as it's intended.

---

I ended up going on safari, and created a repo for this, cause i didn't know of a site (umm.. didn't check) that will precompile less in a fiddle… so:

- repo: https://github.com/ptim/Stack-Overflow-22850627
- demo: http://ptim.github.io/Stack-Overflow-22850627/

Comment: and now i know about github pages :)

Comment: You could have probably used jsFiddle, included all the less files and the less.js compiler, but that may have been just as much work to accomplish.